# Replicate excel solver in R

Tags: r, function, solver

I am wondering if there is a simple function to solve the following problem in R:

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

- Variable 'A' with values c(10, 35, 90)
- Variable 'B' with values c(3, 4, 17, 18, 50, 40, 3)

Now I know that the sum of various values in B equal the values in A, e.g. '3 + 4 + 3 = 10' and '17 + 18 = 35', which always balances out in the complete dataset.

**Question**

Is there a function that can sum these values in B, through trial and error I suppose, and match the correctly summed values with A? For example, the function tries to sum 3 + 4 + 18, which is 25 and retries this because 25 is not a value in A.

I have tried several solutions myself but one problem that I often encountered was the fact that A always has less observations than B.

I would be very thankful if someone can help me out here! If more info is needed please let me know.

Cheers,

Daan

**Edit**

This example is with simplified numbers. In reality, it is a large dataset, so I am looking for a scalable solution.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem know as the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and there are a ton of examples online of how to solve it using dynamic programming, or greedy algorithms.

To give you an answer that just works, the package `adagio` has an implementation:

```
library(adagio)

sums = c(10, 35, 90)
values = c(3, 4, 17, 18, 50, 40, 3)


for(i in sums){
  #we have to subset the values to be less than the value
  #otherwise the function errors:
  print(subsetsum(values[values < i], i))
}
```

The output for each sum is a list, with the val and the indices in the array, so you can tidy up the output depending on what you want from there.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, many thanks for this answer, definitely helps out. Would you happen to know if this scalable? My 'real' dataset has many more values, which are not so straightforward as the example I gave. 

Which means I cannot type out all the values, which would become a problem as there are NA's in variable A and you cannot change NA to 0 because that would give an error in this particular function.

Comment: it should be scalable, the idea would be to import your data as a data frame and apply the function to each row of the data, with a prestep of cleaning it. The exact method would depend on your data, and how you want it to be output

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following but I am affraid is not scalable.
For the case of 3 summands you have

```
x <- expand.grid(c(3, 4, 17, 18, 50, 40, 3),#building a matrix of the possible combinations of summands
                 c(3, 4, 17, 18, 50, 40, 3),
                 c(3, 4, 17, 18, 50, 40, 3))
x$sums <-rowSums(x) #new column with possible sums
idx<- x$sums%in%c(10, 35, 90) #checking the sums are in the required total
x[idx,]

        Var1 Var2 Var3 sums
2      4    3    3   10
8      3    4    3   10
14     3    4    3   10
44     4    3    3   10
50     3    3    4   10
56     3    3    4   10
92     3    3    4   10
98     3    3    4   10
296    4    3    3   10
302    3    4    3   10
308    3    4    3   10
338    4    3    3   10
```

For the case of 2 summands

```
x <- expand.grid(c(3, 4, 17, 18, 50, 40, 3),
                 c(3, 4, 17, 18, 50, 40,3))
x$sums <-rowSums(x) 
idx<- x$sums%in%c(10, 35, 90)
#Results
x[idx,]
   Var1 Var2 sums
18   18   17   35
24   17   18   35
34   40   50   90
40   50   40   90
```

Comment: Hi Chriss, thank you so much for the fast response! I think that is a smart approach indeed.

Unfortunately, my 'real' dataset is on a large scale, which makes a manual grid search difficult. I am trying to find out if there is a way to use your solution and make it scalable as well.